# Does a Degree of Conditional Independence Make Sense?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics

Conditional independence implies

$$p(A, B \, | \, C) = p(A \, | \, C)\:p(B \, | \, C).$$

If the two sides are equal, then $A$, and $B$ are independent conditional on $C$ and there's nothing more to it.

But what if they are roughly equal? Does that suggest anything? If you were to compute conditional independence empirically from a dataset, how could you then decide how close to equality is close enough?

Comment: Does the conditional nature of the independence have anything to it? Couldn't you ask this same question about (unconditional) independence? (After all, unconditional independence is just independence conditional on $\Omega$.)

Comment: ^ Yes, conditional independence doesn't have anything to do with it. $C$ could be the empty set for example.

Comment: the good old fashioned standard method here is a 2x2 chi squared table.

Answer (score 1):

Since independent and uncorrelated are the same for two Bernoulli variables, and since indicator functions for random events are Bernoulli, the simplest answer is to get a confidence interval (or a credible interval, if you're a Bayesian) for the correlation of $I_A$ with $I_B$ and see whether it includes $0$.